# Error: Could not find or load main class in flutter after updating android studio to 4.1

Tags: android, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVToV.png)

I am getting this error [as in picture]when I run "flutter doctor -v" after updating android studio to 4.1

''' Flutter (Channel dev, 1.24.0-10.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1198], locale en-IN)

```
• Flutter version 1.24.0-10.2.pre at C:\Flutter\flutter

• Framework revision 022b333a08 (10 days ago), 2020-11-18 11:35:09 -0800

• Engine revision 07c1eed46b

• Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-29.10.beta)
```

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)

```
• Android SDK at C:\Users\ABDUL KABEER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2

• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\ABDUL KABEER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java

• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

X Android license status unknown.

  Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.

  See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
```

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)

```
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio

• Flutter plugin can be installed from:

   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter

• Dart plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
```

[√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)

```
• VS Code at C:\Users\ABDUL KABEER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code

• Flutter extension version 3.16.0
```

[!] Connected device

```
! No devices available
```

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.'''

and I when I run flutter doctor --android-licenses

i get this error : Error: Could not find or load main class KABEER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\..

Answer (score 0):

To get it right make sure your name does not have any white space between it.... E.g:
Is " KABEER\ " all your  name characters ?

Comment: how can i solve this problem if my user name is like mike tyson\appdata